# Which operations in the Sublime Text 2 API are thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, sublimetext2, sublimetext, python-multithreading, sublime-text-plugin

In the Sublime Text 3 API, [all operations are threadsafe](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html):

> #### Threading
>
> All API functions are thread-safe ...

but in the Sublime Text 2 API, this is not the case. As I've [personally learned to my displeasure](https://github.com/ExplodingCabbage/sublime-gitignorer/commit/c7e735d4bc7fd5a11b70f5bd96562ac5e6a919ab), some operations will, in an unpredictable and OS-dependent way, fail when called from threads other than the main thread with the message

> RuntimeError: Must call on main thread, consider using sublime.set_timeout(function, timeout)

I can track down one assurance about thread safety in the Sublime Text 2 docs (emphasis mine):

> #### set_timeout(callback, delay)
>
> Calls the given callback after the given delay (in milliseconds). Callbacks with an equal delay will be run in the order they were added. ***It is safe to call setTimeout from multiple threads.***

But wrapping everything in `set_timeout` calls is tedious and hard to understand. Are there any other API methods I can safely use from off the main thread if I aim to support Sublime Text 2, or is heavy use of `set_timeout` the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Sublime Text 3 porting guide](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html), the only thread-safe method in Sublime Text 2 is `set_timeout`:

> In Sublime Text 2, only the `set_timeout` method was thread-safe. In
>   Sublime Text 3, every API method is thread-safe.